# Read a file and save the lines in an array with c

Tags: arrays, c, string, file, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to read a given `file` and write its lines into an `array`. At first, i'm not `dynamically allocating` the variable (maze) that will store the lines of the `file`. This is my `code` until now.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
 
    char c, maze[300][300], buffer[1000] = {'\0'};
    int ch = 0, column, row, columns = 0, rows = 0;
    
    FILE* file = fopen("boards/0.txt", "r+");

    if ( file )
    {
        while( fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file) != NULL)
            rows+=1;
    }
    // rows will count the number of rows 
    else
    {
        printf("There's no such file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    // and  columns  will count the number of columns
    columns = (strlen(buffer) - 1);

    // write the content file into an matriz
    for (row = 0; row < rows ; row++)
    {
  
        for (column = 0; column < columns; column++)
        {
          
            if(fscanf(file, "%c", &maze[row][column]) != 1)
                exit(1);

        }
        
    }

    fclose(file);
    // print rows
    for (row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        
        for (column = 0; column < columns; column++)
        {
            printf("%c",maze[row][column]);
            

        }
        
    }

    
    return 0;

}
```

This is the input file:

```
....*.....................
..........................
........*........*........
.....*....................
...............*....*.....
..*.......*...............
............*.............
..........................
..............*...........
..................*.......
..*.......*......*........
....*..*..................
...**.....................
..........*...............
....................*.....
..........................
....**....................
......................*...
```

The output should be the same, but nothing happens. I understand that I'm supposed to `dynamically allocate` the `array`, but I'm not sure how to fit this into the code to make it work.

Comment: After the `while` loop the file position is at the end of the file. `rewind` or re-open the file to position it back to the beginning before the next loop.

Comment: Why do 2 passes? Just read directly into maze.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem of your solution is that you did not reset the file position after finishing the first read.
You should use `fseek(file, SEEK_SET, 0)` before the second read.

The other problem was that you read the `newline` characters with `fscanf` into a maze position, I suppose that you did not want that :)

You can do this process in one pass:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char maze[300][300] = { 0 };
    int column = 0, row = 0, columns = 0, rows = 0;

    FILE* file = fopen("boards/0.txt", "r");
    if (file) {
        while (fgets(&maze[rows][0], 300, file) != NULL) {
            rows++;
        }

        columns = strlen(&maze[0][0]) - 1;
    } else {
        printf("There's no such file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    fclose(file);
    // print rows
    for (row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        for (column = 0; column < columns; column++) {
            printf("%c", maze[row][column]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I took advantage and went to understand better how fseek works. Thanks.